# Why is there so much empty space on some DF screens?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In some Dwarf Fortress screens, there's a lot of empty space. For example, on the health screen, I need to scroll through the units even though they'd fit on one screen if all the space was used. There's also horizontal scrolling for some reason.

Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 34.10 (May 21), horizontal scrolling on most screens has been fixed, including the screens for animals, kitchen, units, stocks, buildings and many others.

The hospital screen has not been fixed yet, but it seems like Toady is putting some effort into the user interface.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately not. The game is still very much a work in progress and the UI is rather low on the list of priorities.

Comment: -1, harsh truth

Comment: In theory you could file a bug...but I'm not sure if the developers will appreciate that.

Comment: @Bobby it's not really a bug. Besides, I'm pretty sure Toady's seen these screens plenty of times.

Answer (score 3):

It's like that because most of the UI code basically doesn't acknowledge the possibility of more than 80 columns existing.  No, you can't do anything about it.  May as well play in the default window size, pretty much.

Answer (score -1):

The "fix" for so much empty space is to use a larger font. You can do that by setting your dwarf fortress to use "graphic" mode, and select a larger font picture to be used. There are many available dwarf fortress "font sets" in different styles and sizes at the dwarf fortress wiki. Note that this doesn't make dwarf fortress display more information--- it just makes the information take up more of your screen space.